# Rutas y Href en el sidebar menu

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

tengo el siguiente problema, me aparece un signo de interrogación "?" en vez de "/" en mi link de la opción "seguridad (security)" del menu sidebar o url

URL
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sidebar menu
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Rutas
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Controlador
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Router list
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo solucionar eso?

Gracias!

Comment: El signo de pregunta ¿solo aparece en tu ruta de 'seguridad' o en algún otra más?

Comment: podrias publicar tus rutas? `php artisan route:list`, para poder ayudarte mejor

Comment: @LeviArista, si, solo aparece el problema en esa ruta "security" desde el menu sidebar.

Comment: @Shassain, listo, lista de rutas publicada.

Comment: Intenta cambiar el orden de tus rutas, poniendo primero la ruta `panel/securirty/{id}` antes que `panel/security`

Comment: @LeviArista, las tengo ordenadas como tu comentas

Comment: intenta ponerle nombres diferentes, por ejemplo "security.edit" y "security.update"

Comment: @Felipe Entonces intenta invertir el orden, algunas veces el hecho de pasar un parámetro bloquea a la ruta siguiente. Para ver el orden de tus rutas ejecuta: `php artisan route:list --sort`

Comment: @LeviArista, hice eso y el problema persiste, me tiene de brazos cruzados

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema se encuentra en que tienes dos rutas con el mismo `name`, por lo cual laravel buscar el ultimo y omite el resto, entonces como tu ultima ruta definida con el `name` security es : `Route::put('/panel/security','UserController@securityUpdate')->name('segurity')`, es a este al cual se redirige y no asi al primero como lo deseas.

La solución es simple, cambia a uno de estos el nombre o a ambos que es lo que te recomiendo.

**En tu web.php**

```
Route::get('/panel/security/{id}','UserController@securityEdit')->name('segurity.edit')
Route::put('/panel/security','UserController@securityUpdate')->name('segurity.update')
```

y tu vista para la edicion:

```
<a href='{{route('security.edit',auth()->user()->id)}}'>editar</a>
```

o para la actualizacion:

```
<form role="form" action="{{route(security.update)}}" method="put">
....mucho codigo
</form>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, funcionó al fin, tengo otro problema ahora respecto al formulario, pero como decían, nombres en las rutas